# setTimeout within function fails

Tags: javascript, function, settimeout

This function accepts an argument, whichImage. This is the object HTMLImageElement for the image we are working with. The image width will be halved, and then after 3 seconds, it will return to normal width. However, the setTimeout code, which is supposed to execute after 3 seconds, fails, with the error message that whichImage is not defined. What do I need to correct to make this function work?

```
function resizeImageFunction(whichImage){
    // Get the width of the image
    alert(whichImage);
    var width = whichImage.width;
    var halfwidth = Math.round(width/2);
    whichImage.width=halfwidth;
    setTimeout("whichImage.width=width;",3000);
}
```

Comment: You maybe want to accept some of the answers to reward them?

Answer (score 1):

```
function resizeImageFunction(whichImage){
    // Get the width of the image
    alert(whichImage);
    var width = whichImage.width;
    var halfwidth = Math.round(width/2);
    whichImage.width=halfwidth;

    setTimeout(function(){
        whichImage.width=width;
    },3000);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The explanation for your problem is as follows:

When you pass a string to `setTimeout()`, that string will be evaluated by `eval()` in the global scope.  Thus any function you call or variable you reference there must be available from the global scope.  That explains why you can't reference a local variable or an argument to your function because neither or those are in the global scope so when `eval()` tries to find them, it looks in the global scope and they aren't there.

When you change the `setTimeout()` function to this using an inline anonymous function:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    whichImage.width = width;
}, 3000);
```

now you have real javascript code (not a string) that is evaluated in place where it exists with no use of `eval()` and because of closures you have full access to the local variables and arguments of the enclosing function which gives you access to both `whichImage` (an argument) and `width` (a local variable) so your code works.

This is reason #14 which you should always use real javascript function references or anonymous function declarations instead of passing a string to `setTimeout()`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your block of code in an anonymous function like:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    whichImage.width=width;
}, 3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
setTimeout(function() {
   whichImage.width=width;
},3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use eval for this

```
setTimeout(function() { whichImage.width=width; } ,3000);
```

Here is is your function

```
function resizeImageFunction(whichImage){
    var halfwidth = Math.round(width/2);
    whichImage.width=halfwidth;
    setTimeout(function() { whichImage.width=width; } ,3000);
}
```